# Django, managing debug flag in settings.py

Tags: python, django

Say you have

- base_settings.py
- debug_settings.py
- product_settings.py

in debug_settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
from base_settings import *
```

in product_settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
from base_settings import *
```

in base_settings.py

```
# this condition check is problamatic, I don't think I can define DEBUG variable outside of `base_settings.py` ?
if DEBUG:
   foo()
```

How do you have a common base_settings.py which has conditional code dependant on variable (DEBUG) whose value can be changed from the importing module? (from debug_settings, product_settings)

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to use environment variables

in debug_settings.py:

```
os.environ["DEBUG"] = "TRUE"
```

in product_settings.py:

```
os.environ["DEBUG"] = "FALSE"
```

then in base_settings.py:

```
if os.getenv("DEBUG", "TRUE"): #The second argument specifies the default in case "DEBUG" has not been set
    foo()
```